# ruby method looping without loop

Tags: ruby, methods

hi I am having a problem with a method i have written.  When the method has finished executing it runs its first 2 lines again even though there is no loop. can anyone tell me why?

here is the code

```
def print(students)
  if sort_by?("letter") then students = letter_sort(students) end
  if sort_by?("cohort") then students = cohort_sort(students) end
  print_header
  i = 0
  until i = students.length do 
    student_name = get_student_name(students[i][:name])
    puts "#{i+1}. #{student_name} (#{students[i][:cohort]} cohort)"
    i = i + 1
  end
end
```

The two if statements at the top are the ones being executed. Here is the sort_by? method I've written as well.

```
def sort_by?(string)
  puts "would you like to sort by #{string}?"
  puts "Enter y/n:"
  input = gets.chomp.downcase
  while input != "n" or input != "y"
      if input == "n"
          return false
      elsif input == "y"
          return true
      end       
  end
end
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: In `until i = students.length` line, didn't you mean `until i == students.length`?

Comment: I believe the problem lies outside of the code you posted. More ruby-ish would be to iterate over the students like this: `students.each_with_index do |student, idx| ....`.

Comment: Oh, you enter an inifinite loop when neither "y" nor "n" is entered in the sort_by? method. Put a `input = gets.chomp.downcase` inside the loop (another `else`?) in order to re-read from the user.

Comment: agreed with felix